# using javascript to add an OnClick event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to make classes that cause onclick events. So say for example in a form. I want to give that form field a class. Every time I add a certain class to a field I want it to generate an onclick command to the form field.

The reason I am doing this is I want to add analytic tracking to each form field, but I am using gravity forms so I want to be able to create forms on the fly without editing each one. If I could create a class called .name and have that class add this `onClick="mixpanel.track('Name_field');"`  to the form input, then I could track everytime a user clicks inside the form to fill it out. This way I could track each step of the form and see when users leave.

So  list would be

```
.name  that would add onClick="mixpanel.track('Name_field');"
.email  that would add onClick="mixpanel.track('Email_field');"
.phone  that would add onClick="mixpanel.track('pnone_field');"
```

I hope that makes sense. Thanks for any help you can give. I am fairly new to javascript so please be easy on me. html and css I am a pro but javascript is my next mountain to climb.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Y'know there's companies out there that do this for a living, and are pretty good at it (for good or ill).

Comment: [ClickTales](http://www.clicktale.com/) is who I remember, but there's others, some free (for a while).

Comment: If you are open to using jquery you can select all the inputs which has the class attribute and add the click handler:
`$('#formid input[class]').each(function(){ $(this).click(mixpanel.track($(this).attr('class').val()+'_field'))})`

Answer (score 1):

It would be far more efficient to delegate so you only have one event handler:

```
var f = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var t = e.srcElement || e.target, m;
  while (t !== this && (!t.className || !(m = t.className.match(/\b(name|email|phone)\b/)))) {
    t = t.parentNode;
  }
  if (m) {
    switch (m[0]) {
      case "name": mixpanel.track("Name_field"); break;
      case "email": mixpanel.track("Email_field"); break;
      case "phone": mixpanel.track("phone_field"); break;
    }
  }
};
if (document.body.attachEvent) {
  document.body.attachEvent("onclick", f, true);
} else {
  document.body.addEventListener("click", f, true);
}
```

Comment: Do you really think your classname dispatcher running on every click on `body` is more efficient than individual element listeners?

Comment: Alone, no. But ultimately the gain depends on how many elements there are, how frequently they are added/removed, and how often the user is likely to click (usually, it's about 1-2 times per page on average!)